# How can I convert List<String> to GroupMatcher<JobKey>

Tags: java, list, spring-mvc, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

How to convert List to GroupMatcher ?

My code Just Like This.

```
List<String> jobGroupNames = scheduler.getJobGroupNames();
```

Now I want to check

```
for (GroupMatcher<JobKey> jobGroup : jobGroupNames) {
}
```

Here jobGroupNames is List, So I'm Getting this error

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type String to GroupMatcher<JobKey>
```

Comment: Try to get GorupMatcher like `GroupMatcher.groupEquals(jobGroupName)` for each `scheduler.getJobGroupNames()`

Comment: It won't work, `List<String>` argument is not applicable for `groupEquals()`

Comment: Because you are doing wrong. Try to read how to iterate list.  http://crunchify.com/how-to-iterate-through-java-list-4-way-to-iterate-through-loop/

Comment: Thanks, It Worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jobGroupNames is a list of String, That's why you should iterate like below.

// loop jobs by group

List<String> jobGroupNames = scheduler.getJobGroupNames();

for (String groupName : jobGroupNames ) {

// And to get Job keys :

    for (JobKey jobKey : scheduler.getJobKeys(GroupMatcher.jobGroupEquals(groupName))) {
    }
}
```